# Recommendation on how to document Websocket API

Tags: ios, sockets, websocket, socket.io, documentation

I've written a Websocket-API using socket.io.

Let's say that after establishing the connection the server waits for a `login`-event with a payload like `{username: String, password: String}`.

The server then answers with the events `login:accept` or `login:deny`.

Only if the login was successful the server then responds to an event `tweets:get` with an event `tweets` (that has an array of tweets as payload).

Is there a standardized way to document APIs like this one? Do you have any recommendations and experiences?

Answer (score 17):

There's [AsyncApi node tool](https://github.com/asyncapi/asyncapi) to create machine-readable definitions, it's very similar to swagger but for asynchronous APIs, and there are tools to generate HTML such as [AsyncApi docgen](https://github.com/asyncapi/docgen) and widdershins.

You can build your documentation using either `yaml` or `json`, as an example:

```
asyncapi: "1.0.0"

topics:
    "tweets:get":
        publish:
            $ref: "#/components/messages/getTweets"
    tweets:
        subscribe:
            $ref: "#/components/messages/tweetsList"
```

*Where`topics` = `events`, `publish` = `emit`, and `subscribe` = `on` in socket.io terms*

after saying that, authentication using socket.io mostly depends on tokens, the user would send authentication token in the `options.query` at the connection initiation time, and you authenticate the token at the backend, then you can disconnect the connection if authentication failed. No need for `login:accept` or `login:deny`

```
const socket = io('http://localhost?token=abc');
// or
const socket = io({ query: { token: 'cde' } });
```

Comment: `Something went wrong:
Error: undefined is not a valid value for major version.`

Comment: What about "namespace" and "rooms"? How can we document them with asyncAPI?